# Dynamic rows of divs (boxes) using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have a variable number of boxes and I'd like to display as many as I can without forcing the viewer to scroll horizontally, there should also be a certain space in between them. This means that the boxes will have to move to the next or previous "row" if the browser is resized.

How do I achieve this using divs and CSS?

Thanks in advance :-)

*P.S: Enjoy my fine art skills:*

[image]

Comment: use inline-block, take a look at picasaweb's implementation

Comment: Thanks, inline-block works great (used without a container, just the black divs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is setting the red divs width and/or height as "percentage" and setting your small-black divs `float: left`.

Example:

```
<div style="width: 80%"><div style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 10px; float: left;"></div> </div>
```

This will let your red div resize as soon as viewer resizes the window.>

Comment: You don't need to apply any special style to the outer `<div>`, and it will automatically take up the width of the page (or whatever its parent element is).

Comment: It seems like my container, the outside div, ignores the rows and height of the boxes inside. It has the 80% width but it's not vertically stretching... Hmm. It works other than that.

Comment: Make sure that, your red div is set positioned "relative". If you want your div extend dynamicly you shouldn't set height of it. Leave it blank.

Comment: @Chris: add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` inside your container, after the last box. That should fix it ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Scaryguy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691670/dynamic-rows-of-divs-boxes-using-css/3691691#3691691)'s is answer pretty much correct. But the **outer div** should have `overflow: hidden` for the conteiner to work properly.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/QCf4U/

[image: cssexample]

The code in the example has all the red boxes with `float: left`. And there are 4 blue divs that contain (the first 2 blue divs are stuck together on the top):

1. No clear and no float, and has 3 red divs inside
2. No clear and no float, and has 3 red divs inside
3. Has `clear: left`, and 5 red divs inside
4. Has `overflow: hidden`, and 5 red divs inside

Notice that without clear nor float nor `overflow: hidden` on the container, your red divs on container 1 and 2 will be next to each other (not following the container).

You can see that for the container blue div to get its correct vertical size you have to use `overflow: hidden` (or maybe `float` there too).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `overflow: hidden` is a better solution for clearfixes

Comment: You don't have to use a float. You can use an overflow:hidden, you can use a clearfix, and hasLayout triggering for IE.

Comment: Oh, you are right guys. I didn't know about overflow:hidden. I will fix my anwser. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, overflow:hidden did the trick. Who knows how to let the divs stretch individually depending on the contents? Let's say div #3 has a really long line in it, what style do I apply to make sure the div stretches for it?